# Continue Behat execution on exception

Tags: testing, automation, behat

I am writing a step definition for a behat in which I need to check if array is empty and if array is not empty print the array and fail the step. To do this I have written following code in step definition.

```
if (!empty($issues)) {
      print_r($issues);
      throw new \Exception("Above issues were found for");
}
```

Currently when exception is shown it stop the execution and does not execute future scenarios.

Comment: Can you add the stack-trace of the exception? the only way it would not execute the other scenarios is if you are getting a php fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fail only a step from the entire scenario.

If any of the steps of a scenario fails then the scenario fails and the rest of the steps from the scenario will not be executed since the rest of the steps should continue the actions from previous ones that failed.

Please recheck the logic of the scenario and review the behat/bdd documentation.

Comment: Hey @lauda, I failing the scenario itself. Once the scenario is failed I want to continue the script execution for other scenarios.

Comment: The other scenarios will be executed unless you got a `Fatal Exception`, in this case you need to handle it and to throw a regular exception.

Answer (score 0):

Jeevan, Behat does not stop script execution if one or multiple scenarios fail in a feature file. For example, if one feature file "test.feature" has 10 scenarios, if you have run the command to run the entire feature file as behat features/test.feature, then all the scenarios will run continuously even if Scenario 2 fails.
In the end, you would see the summary as per the screenshot attached.

[image: Results summary]

Answer (score 0):

Behat output formatter to show progress as TAP and fails inline.

[image]

https://github.com/drevops/behat-format-progress-fail